# Electron - throttle flow of messages from main to render process

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, ipcrenderer

I am currently having some issues receiving an constant stream of active windows from my main process to my renderer process (in Angular). I know receiving second-by-second updates will break my app as it does, so I am trying to throttle it a bit using setTimeout. But this still doesn't work. How can I fix this?

**renderer - component in Angular**

```
  ipc: IpcRenderer | undefined | null;

  constructor(private electronService: ElectronService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getActiveWindow();
  }

  getActiveWindow() {
    while(this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
      this.ipc = this.electronService.ipcRenderer;
      this.ipc.send('get-active-window');
      this.ipc.on('get-active-window-reply', (_event, reply) => {
        console.log(reply);
      });
    }
  }
```

**main.js**

```
const activeWindows = require('electron-active-window');

ipcMain.on('get-active-window', (_event, _arg) => {
  let i = 0;
  setTimeout(function () {
    activeWindows().getActiveWindow().then((result) => {
      win.webContents.send("get-active-window-reply", result)
    })
  }, 10000 * i)
});
```

So far I've tried the following, but this only displays the active window once. I'd like to keep track of all the changes:

**renderer - component in Angular**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getActiveWindow();
  }

  getActiveWindow() {
    if(this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
      this.ipc = this.electronService.ipcRenderer;
      this.ipc.send('get-active-window');
      this.ipc.on('get-active-window-reply', (_event, reply) => {
        console.log(reply);
      });
    }
  }
```

**main.js**

```
ipcMain.on('get-active-window', (_event, _arg) => {
  activeWindows().getActiveWindow().then((result) => {
    win.webContents.send("get-active-window-reply", result)
  });
});
```

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with this code. You have a while loop that keeps sending events and registering handlers. The response handler just sends a delayed response. Both sides are somewhat asynchronous in nature. Think about what happens when with your current code and what you want and try to rework from there.

Comment: @Clashsoft thanks for replying. I've updated my question to show where I currently am with this. The second attempt seems to only get the window titles once. I'd like to make this real-time. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You're only receiving the active windows once because you're only requesting them once in your `ngOnInit`.

So in my opinion you've currently two options.

1. You're requesting the information every few seconds from the client
2. You let your Electron application notify the client about the windows

**Option 1: (only solution afaik)**

**render.component**

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

...

getActiveWindow() {
  if(this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
    this.ipc = this.electronService.ipcRenderer;
    
    this.ipc.on('get-active-window-reply', (_event, reply) => {
      console.log(reply);
    });

    // A request directly to get "instant" feedback
    this.ipc.send('get-active-window');

    // You could also use setInterval but I prefer rxjs more ;)
    // Don't forget to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy
    interval(2000).subscribe(() => {
      this.ipc.send('get-active-window');
    });
  }
}
```

This solution creates a lot of overhead since you don't need to update the active windows every few seconds, so I **do  <s>not</s>  recommend** this one.

**Option 2 (<s>recommended</s> not working):**

**main.js**

```
// Sends a message every time a BrowserWindow is created
app.on('browser-window-created', (event, window) => {
  this.sendActiveWindows();
});

// Respond to the client request
ipcMain.on('get-active-window', (_event, _arg) => {
   this.sendActiveWindows();
});

// Helper function
sendActiveWindows(){
  activeWindows().getActiveWindow().then((result) => {
    win.webContents.send("get-active-window-reply", result)
  });
}
```

If you need also the information when a windows is being closed you need to add a listener to `BrowserWindow.on('closed',...)` (more [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-closed)) and notify your client then as well.

**render.component.ts (only comments added)**

```
getActiveWindow() {
  if(this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
    this.ipc = this.electronService.ipcRenderer;
    // Request the currently active windows, 
    // otherwise this info is missing until new window is created
    this.ipc.send('get-active-window');
    this.ipc.on('get-active-window-reply', (_event, reply) => {
      console.log(reply);
    });
  }
}
```

This solution is more suitable since your client is only getting notified if the number of windows changes, so I **do recommend** this one

**Update**

After clarifying the problem in the chat you cannot use option 2 since you want to detect the active windows of the OS and not of your Electron app.
Due that info **option 1** is the only **valid solution** here

Comment: getActiveWindow should probably return the Observable from interval, otherwise good solution!

Comment: This depends on you ;) You could also assign the subscription to a variable inside of `getActiveWindow` in that case it would not be necessary. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the this @Batajus. I've tried option 2 and it doesn't seem to work. My *main.js* is at https://pastebin.com/uV2b12Nm, and my component code is here: https://pastebin.com/Ae4Bx0Pu.

Comment: Option 1 works, but I get the error `(node:22168) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 get-active-window-reply listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit     
(Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)` in the console, so its probably not a good idea.

Comment: It picks up the new window title when I initialise the program, but it doesn't pick it up when I switch to another one, for example Telegram.

Comment: Why does it seem like option 2 is not working? Regarding the console message, are you adding the event listener inside of the interval?

Comment: Are you creating a new window for Telegram or are you just loading another url?

Comment: So the above is part of a desktop app, so I am opening a seperate Telegram/Snipping Tool/Discord instance. I want to get the name of the active window whenever that happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240018/discussion-between-batajus-and-methuselah).